# Protect an Azure Private DNS zone against accidental deletion without resource locks

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-dns

I want to protect my Azure private DNS against accidental deletion. At first a placed resource locks on the DNS zone. But this prevented me from deleting individual virtual network links (microsoft.network/privatednszones/virtualnetworklinks) as these are child resources, and thus also locked. I want to still be able to delete these without removing the lock first. I only want to protect the whole Zone from being deleted.

Is it possible to place locks that wont be inherited to child resources?

Answer (score 0):

To protects azure private DNS against accidental deletion. Applying a `CanNotDelete` lock to whole zone can prevent from being deleted. *CanNotDelete* denotes that a resource is accessible to view and edit but cannot be deleted by other users According to my knowledge resource locks on the DNS zone ***Locks are inherited by child resources only***

The Basic structure of resource locks states that a ***lock applies to child resources as well,*** thus if you place a lock on your resource group, all of its resources both existing and newly added will be protected.

When you apply a lock at parent scope, all resources inside of the scope inherit the same lock. Even resources you add later will have the same parent lock

***Additionally,*** you can make use of a custom role to enable full control over a DNS resource, preventing the user account from deleting zones or modifying records of other types.

***Reference:***

[protecting-against-zone-deletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-protect-zones-recordsets#protecting-against-zone-deletion)

[Easiest-way-to-prevent-accidental-resource-deletion](https://www.adrienvandriel.com/articles/the-easiest-way-to-prevent-accidental-resource-deletion-in-azure)